# CURL -X POST to PHP

Tags: php, curl, post

I need to post those values to php. In the documentation they give like:

> curl -X POST 'https://api.telapi.com/v2/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{CallSid}/Recordings.json' -u '{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}' -d 'Record=true'

Here is the full documentation; http://docs.zang.io/docs/voice-effects

I have to set the voice pich, octaves, rate and such as defined in that page. 
How do I do that ?

Comment: do you have a good php background ?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.tld" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "AccountSid:AuthToken"); # -u option 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Record=true"); # -d option
$result=curl_exec($ch);
```

---

You don't need to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`, `POST` is used by default when `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is set.

Comment: you have mixed the -u and -d options

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this and let you know how it goes. Appericated.